# Remote MacMini only displays on screens when accessed remotely

Tags: macos, remote-desktop, external-display, remote-control

I have a MacMini we use to display onto 3 70" screens, usually it's used for music tv etc but occasionally used for presentations.

currently the MacMini is only outputting to the screens when I remote onto the machine, as soon as I disconnect the session the output appears to drop, however the machine is still streaming the music tv, just not outputting it.

I've set the machine to never go to sleep and the display to never dim.

Late 2012 Mac mini
OSX 10.11.3
Processor 2.5GHz i5
RAM 4GB 1600MHz DDR3
GPU Intel HD Graphics 4000 1.5GB

Any help greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Waited until the presentation was over and restarted the Mac Mini, issue has now gone away, we think it's the actual AV equipment itself that is causing the issue rather than the Mac.

Comment: Yes that is most likely the case